# Listchar "precedes" does not show up

Tags: listchars

I have a long data line:

[image]

When I switch off wrapping and place the cursor somewhere in the middle, it looks like this:

[image]

Here I see the "extends' listchar, but not the "precedes".

I also made the window smaller and larger (up to fullscreen), tried various intervals within the line, started vim with `.vimrc` and `.vim/` removed, and used `set listchars=precedes:a,extends:b`: nothing revealed the missing "precedes" char.

Is this a bug or do I have to do more than setting the listchars?

---

(Debian 9.6, Vim 8.0)

---

Update on 2023-07-06:

I am now on Debian 12.0, Vim 9.0

"precedes" and "extends" now show either both or not at all:

[image]

If you want to see "precedes" and "extends" generally, but are not interested in the rest of the `listchars` functionality, add this to your `.vimrc` file:

[image]

Then you have:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "extends" char is always visible when wrapping is off and there are additional chars to the right.

The other listchars (including "precedes") are only visible when the option `list` is set.

Don't know why.

Comment: Although the problem is not solved, I have marked your answer as "accepted", because I wanted to know, whether there is something wrong with my system, or it is a general bug. And a bug it is, for either should both characters being displayed without `:set list`, or none. I could file a bug report at Github, but with currently 600+ open issues I would rather wait until this number is down to 20 :-).

Answer (score 0):

The listchars option lets you change the characters used to represent special characters such as line wrapping and tabulations. In this case, we want to use listchars to display the precedes (<) and extends (>) characters.

In Vim, the precedes (<) and extends (>) characters are used to indicate wrapped lines. When a line is too long to fit within the width of the screen, Vim wraps it onto the next line, and the precedes (<) character appears at the end of the preceding line, while the extends (>) character appears at the beginning of the continued line.

```
set list
set listchars=
set listchars+=precedes:<,extends:>
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I think this answer would benefit greatly from additional detail on _why_ it helps to show the precedes and extends characters. Please [edit] to explain.